# Validation - if statement not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation, if-statement

I'm trying to use Javascript for a simple form validation. In this case, I have an email text input and I want it to error if the email is not a valid email or the email address is already taken. The valid email part is erroring fine, but the email address is already taken part always passes.

**Here is my script code**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
function valemail() 
{
var email = $('input#email').val();
var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length)
    {
    document.getElementById("email").style.border="3px solid red";
    document.getElementById('email_error').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('email_error').innerHTML = 'A valid email address is required';
    } else {
if ($.trim(email) != '') 
{

    $.post('../ajax/registeremail.php', {email: email}, function(data) 
    {
        if ($.trim(data) == 'That email address is already in use. If you have created an account, 
<a href="../login.php">Login</a>') 
        {
            document.getElementById("email").style.border="3px solid red";
            document.getElementById('email_error').style.display = 'block'; 
            $('div#email_error').text(data);
        } else {
            document.getElementById("email").style.border="3px solid #33FF33";
            document.getElementById('email_error').style.display = 'none'; 
        }
    });
   }
}}
 </script>
```

**My registeremail.php file works on its own and is:**

```
<?php
include('../init.php');
//email validation
if (isset($_POST['email']) === true && empty($_POST['email']) === false) {
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (email_exists($email) === true) {
echo('That email address is already in use. If you have created an account, <a>Login</a>');
} else {
echo('Good');
}
?>
```

The actual text input and div code is

```
      <input class="input" type="text" tabindex="2" placeholder="Email*" style="height:20px;" name="email"  
id="email" onchange="valemail()">
<div id="email_error"></div>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I'm truly perplexed.

Comment: open up the console and find out if there are any errors.

Comment: Why not use jQuery fo real? Seems like a weird mix of vanilla JS and jQ...

Comment: Comparing a variable against a string literal (especially that long) is likely to end in tears. Use a boolean or int type in these situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that what you echo in PHP is

```
That email address is already in use. If you have created an account, <a>Login</a>
```

and what you check for in JavaScript is

```
That email address is already in use. If you have created an account, <a href="../login.php">Login</a>
```

i.e. they are not the same ...

I suggest you return a `1` (true) or `0` (false) and then output the text using JavaScript .. Something like

```
if (email_exists($email) === true) {
   echo('0');
} else {
   echo('1');
}
```

then your JavaScript would be something like

```
if ($.trim(data) == '0') {
    document.getElementById("email").style.border = "3px solid red";
    document.getElementById('email_error').style.display = 'block';
    $('div#email_error').text('That email address is already in use. If you have created an account,<a href="../login.php">Login</a>');
} else {
    document.getElementById("email").style.border = "3px solid #33FF33";
    document.getElementById('email_error').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: oops Sorry ManseUK, didnt know you were posting same solution, or else i wouldnt submit

Comment: @mongy910 do some debugging - i suggest firebug - you can then see the response from PHP and step though the code - checking the variable values as you go. My answer wasnt supposed to be a working solution - just a pointer in the right direction, hence the words *something like*

Comment: Oh my gosh that just helped me more than any answer ever could have! I installed firebug and went to the console and it instantly told me what my error was! turns out I was missing a } at the end of registeremail.php. Thank you a ton!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change your javascript logic to check for the lack of a "Good" response rather than checking for a lengthy error message that you may not be copying exactly.  Change to this:

```
$.post('../ajax/registeremail.php', {email: email}, function(data) 
{
    if ($.trim(data) != 'Good') 
    {
       ...
```

This will both prevent issues with not matching your error message exactly, but also allow you to modify that error message or create other errors without having to change your error detection code.